# Do the "apparent limits" and "true limits" of this excel spread sheet I made make sense?

Tags: statistical-significance

I was asked to create a small snippet of excel from a survey data-set of everyone's documented ages. 
I got the data from the SDA, I filtered the data-set for just 2010. The SDA website generates a frequency distrubtion table of all that data for the respondents. Left being of course the age groups and right being the percentages and the number of people who were counted in that age group.
Here is what that table looks like:
[image]

Then I took the (what I am not sure is correct) number of respondants counted in each group and plugged that data into an excel document and calculated the category midpoint, CM = (highest true limit + lowest true limit) / 2

Does what I have done look correct?:

[image]

From what I gather the "apparent limit" is the rounded/less precise form, and the "true limit" is the non-rounded form.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "apparent limits" and "true limits."  Of what quantity are they the "rounded" and "non-rounded" forms?

Comment: I don't know exactly. I figured it was the decimal at the end and that needed to be truncated. Like when someone says their age they are likely to give their last birthday not 25.5 or 18.8 although those are truer forms. Whereas apparent would be 25 or 18.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fit the table: how could a set of ages between 18 and 19 (to take just the first row) have "truer forms" of 48.8??  The answer may lie in whatever that website means by "weighted N."  You need to consult that website--all we can do is guess and you don't seem to have enough information to help with that.

Comment: Here is the form I am getting the data from: http://sda.berkeley.edu/sdaweb/analysis/exec?formid=tbf&sdaprog=tables&dataset=gss16&sec508=false&row=age%28c%3A+10%2C0%29&filters=year%282010%29&weightlist=COMPWT&columnpct=on&design=complex&cflevel=95&weightedn=on&color=on&ch_type=bar&ch_color=yes&ch_width=600&ch_height=400&ch_orientation=vertical&ch_effects=use2D&decpcts=1&decse=1&decdeft=3&decwn=1&decstats=2